# Use different Android SDK (stock and custom) for each product flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I need to build my app against both a stock Android SDK and a custom Android SDK for a specific device with AOSP modifications.

My thought was to use product flavors in my `build.gradle` to conditionally point to the correct SDK directory. Basically, I'm looking for something to the effect of:

```
productFlavors {
    stock {
        sdk.dir "/path/to/stocksdk"
    }
    mydevice {
        sdk.dir "/path/to/customsdk"
    }
}
```

Looking at the ProductFlavor DSL documentation, there isn't a property to set SDK directory.

What other ways could I achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question but, unfortunately **you cannot** have different SDKs for `productFlavors` or `buildTypes`. You can have it only at the project level.

> Product flavors can customize the following properties:
>
> ```
> minSdkVersion
> targetSdkVersion
> versionCode
> versionName
> package name (overrides value from manifest)
> release signing info (keystore, key alias, passwords,...).
> BuildConfig: Ability to provide custom Java code.
> NDK ABI filter (Not implemented yet)
> test info
> package name for test app (optional, default is <base>.test)
> InstrumentationTestRunner class (optional)
> Additionally, Product Flavor can provide their own source code, resources and manifest.
> ```

And

> A Build Type provides configuration for the following build
>   properties:
>
> ```
> manifest debuggable flag
> native compilation debug flag
> proguard enabled + specific rules (Not implemented yet)
> debug signing flag (ie whether to use debug key or release key)
> package name suffix (2)
> version name suffix (new in milestone 0.3)
> Buildconfig
> DEBUG flag. Set automatically based on the manifest debuggable flag.
> Ability to provide custom Java code.
> ```

[Source (Build System Concepts on http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/)](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts)

> What other ways could I achieve a similar result?

You could make this project a library project and then create wrapper projects with different SDKs, just using the functionality in the library. So now you have a separate wrapper project instead of the `productFlavors` and you can change the `sdk.dir` for each wrapper project in the `local.properties` file.